# Return JSON in Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, lambda

How to I get JSON back from golang without it being encoded as a string? I am using [this project](https://github.com/eawsy/aws-lambda-go-shim) to wrap go code in python so that I can execute it in an AWS lambda function.

My issue is that whether I return  `json.Marshal(obj)` or `string(json.Marshal(obj))` I either get the base64 encoded json or a string representation (e.g. `"{\"bar\": \"foo\"}"`). This is not an appropiate response if you are using the AWS API gateway as it expects pure json like you would get if you returned a json object in Node.js.

Here's my code:

```
package main

import "C"

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "github.com/eawsy/aws-lambda-go-core/service/lambda/runtime"
)

type Response struct {
  StatusCode  int       `json:"statusCode"`
  Headers     map[string]string  `json:"headers"`
  Body        string    `json:"body"`
}

func Handle(evt json.RawMessage, ctx *runtime.Context) (interface{}, error) {
  res := &Response{
    StatusCode: 1,
    Headers: map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    Body: "Hello World",
  }
  content, _ := json.Marshal(res)
  return string(content), nil
}
```

Here's the result I get from AWS:

[image]

Comment: How is `Handle` called and what does the caller do with the return-value?

Comment: Looks like you're not supposed to JSONify the return value (the return type is `interface{}`). It may be marshaling the marshaled string.

Comment: @AndySchweig can you elaborate? If I just return `content, nil`, I will get the base64 encoded json

Comment: What if you return `res, nil`?

Comment: @AndySchweig yep that worked! I look at the source code for the dependency i'm using and the result is getting marshaled so it was getting marshaled twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/l2nrhG9lOA

It looks like the `interface{}` return type is the culprit. Forcing that to a `string` returns a more JSON-looking value. Having an `interface{}` return type makes me think something else is expecting a `struct` or marshal-able return value. Chase the `interface{}` or force a `string` and you should be good.

Comment: I look at the source code for the dependency i'm using and the result is getting marshaled so it was getting marshaled twice

Answer (score 9):

Since AWS Lambda now [officially supports Go](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-go-support-for-aws-lambda/), here is an revised example.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

// Response ...
type Response struct {
    StatusCode int               `json:"statusCode"`
    Headers    map[string]string `json:"headers"`
    Body       string            `json:"body"`
}

// Handle ...
func Handle() (Response, error) {
    return Response{
            StatusCode: 1,
            Headers:    map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            Body:       "Hello World",
        },
        nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handle)
}
```

**(Update below with another example)**

You can also just use a `map[string]interface{}` data type directly without having to create a `type`.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

// Handle ...
func Handle() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    return map[string]interface{}{
            "statusCode": 1,
            "headers":    map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            "body":       "Hello World",
        },
        nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handle)
}
```

Comment: If working with API Gateway's Proxy Integration, see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) for specifics on output format.

Comment: Similarly, if you get a "Malformed Lambda Response" error like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/)

Answer (score 0):

`json.Marshal` does return a pure JSON string. It looks like you're printing it with `%q`. See https://play.golang.org/p/skvAfk-frO.